# Some Bootstrap elements not working in Angular project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, accordion

I'm working on a project with Bootstrap and Angular and it is not working fine. Some elements like dropdowns, accordions, etc doesn't work fine.

It is a little wierd because in a separated HTML file or Codeply everything works fine, but not in my project.

For example, in my attacked code, you can see an accordion example. It works in separade HTML file and Codeply but, in my project, you can see it well but don't do anything. You can click everywhere, but it don't respond (no action, no error, no nothing).

I tried with bootstrap installed version and https reference, with the same result (not working)

[image: Left: My project. Right: Codeply]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Main</title>
<!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../main.css">
    <script src="../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
     -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    


  </head>

<body>
    <div class= "container">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Accordion Item #1
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                EXAMPLE TEXT 1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Accordion Item #2
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              EXAMPLE TEXT 2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Accordion Item #3
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                EXAMPLE TEXT 3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Tried different versions, different import ways, different components (dropdowns, accordions, pop ups...)

Answer (score 0):

The [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#usage-with-javascript-frameworks) states:

> The Bootstrap JavaScript is not fully compatible with JavaScript
> frameworks like Angualar. Both Bootstrap and the framework may attempt to mutate the same DOM element, resulting in bugs like dropdowns that are stuck in the “open” position.

If using JavaScript Frameworks you should consider to use a framework-specific package. In your case it would be [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)